# Use WinForms to select an XML file and deserialize it

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, file-io, xsd

I am a beginner and want to expand my knowledge, so please be gentle. I am trying as hard as I can.

I am making a C# WinForms application, but I will skip most of the functions of the form and jump directly to the point. I have a button that invokes an OpenFileDialog. After the user clicks "OK" and has chosen a file, I need to invoke another method.

So my first of two questions is: **How do I invoke a method with the file selected by the user?** I have searched for three weeks and only found how to copy a file, but only if I know the source folder; I need to work with the file that comes out of the DialogResult.

My second question is about the invoked method I'm trying to write. The selected file must be an XSD that I need to deserialize. I managed to do that with Xsd2Code but only after I manually uploaded the file to my SolutionExplorer. I need to use the file that was selected by the user at runtime (not a static file in my project), do some operations with the produced classes, and then serialize it out to another XSD file.

I didn't manage to use XSD.EXE.

My attempt at operating with the file:

```
private void browseXML_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
    {
        Savef();
    }
}

public void Savef()
{
    string path = @"c:\Test1";
    DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    string fn = "sci.xsd";
    string sp = @"C:\test";
    string tp = path;
    string sf = Path.Combine(sp, fn);
    string df = Path.Combine(tp, fn);
    File.Copy(sf, df, true);
    Transformer.Deserialization();
}
```

And my attempt to deserialize it:

```
public static void Deserialization()
{
    //System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlTextParser(@"C:\Test1\sci.xsd");

    XmlSerializer();
}

private static void XmlSerializer()
{
    //throw new NotImplementedException();
    XmlSerializer reader = new XmlSerializer(typeof (Transformer));
    StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"C:\Test1\sci.xsd");
    Transformer overview = new Transformer();
    overview = (Transformer) reader.Deserialize(file);
    Console.WriteLine("Done");
    Console.WriteLine(overview.proc_type);     
}
```

I have searched and attempted so many things during three and a half months and would appreciate any help you can provide. I want to learn.

Comment: The first question should be answered by this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: OP, not meaning this to be rude but if you have not found the solution to these questions in 3.5 months you must improve your googling skills. By googling 'c# get selected file from openfiledialog' you will get many relevant results to that part of the question. For the second question, 'Deserialization' is not what Xsd2Code does. Xsd2Code creates code from a schema file which is very different from Deserialization.

Comment: Edit1: First of all thank you for the editing of my post. Second EBrown thank you for the link I am attempting it now. Third user469104 you are not rude at all but that is just a partition of the project and I started from zero, learning my way up. To be precise I need an alternative to the java tool "JaxB" and the ability to Marshal and Unmarshal from code to ".xsd" and from ".xsd" to code. Xsd2Code was the suggested alternative. Really sorry for my ignorance I just need help. Thank you.